# login to any site using curl in php

Tags: php, curl

login to a website using curl php

I have tried

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.sitename.com");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookies.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookies.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "username:password");
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

But this does not log in .

Comment: Please rephrase this question as a question. Also, please tell us what you're trying to do, and why your code doesn't work.

Comment: This depends on the site you're trying to login to. But maybe the site is checking the referer?

Comment: It looks like your trying to do HTTPAUTH login.  Most sites don't support this, you have to post a form, which is very different from HTTPAUTH.  So without knowing what site you're trying to do this against its impossible to help you.

Comment: Please note a bug in the above code: `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST` should be an integer parameter, and should be set to 2 (the default). See http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php for more details. If you set the value to `true`, you're actually disabling host checking.

Answer (score 0):

`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, true);` does not make sense.

You may have CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS and CURLOPT_POST mixed up. The correct way is:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
```

Check the manual here: http://no.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php

Answer (score 0):

Correct Code should be :

NOTE : change the values for userName an password as required by the login form 
for the site.

```
$postField = "userName = abc&password=xyz";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.sitename.com");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookies.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookies.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postFields);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "username:password");
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);`
```